# Calling ASP.NET CORE webpage from ASP.NET 3.5 legacy application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

We have created a generalized registration page in ASP.NET Core 2.1 and Angular 5. The page developed in asp.net core is being called from iOS and Android App. We also want to call this page from our web application. Our web application is built in ASP.NET 3.5 Framework. How can we achieve this?

Is the sharing of the cookies possible in ASP.NET 3.5 framework and ASP.NET Core 2.1?

Comment: wouldn't you be better with a centralised _API_ and then each client (iOS, Android, ASP.NET) uses its own native UI and just submits a HTTP request to the API with the data, rather than trying to work with a HTML document which is intended for human beings to use.

Comment: That's a good suggestion @ADyson. But we have around more than 40 apps and doing it for all the apps would be cumbersome. That's why we have created a single page.

Comment: so can't you just redirect the user to this page, and then redirect them back again after they submit the form, if they've come from your 3.5 app? Perhaps there's more to it than that, the context isn't too clear. Is this a legacy app you eventually want to replace entirely with the Core app?

Comment: Redirect will surely work. My only concern is that after the registration is done, I need to set some cookies in the old app(Asp.net 3.5). How should I send the data from the ASP.NET core app. The data contains emailId, customerId.

Comment: well a redirect can contain querystring parameters, can it not? Not ideal to pass this kind of info on the querystring though (unless it's literally just an ID, rather than the actual email address?) since it can find its way into IIS logs etc. Each app would have to set its own cookies though, other applications cannot do that for it - they have no access to the related browser session.

Comment: My concern is not the calling the page in the app. My concern is passing the data from in the web. I don't want to use query string parameters and not sure how cookies sharing work in ASP.NET 3.5 and ASP.NET Core 2.1.

Comment: sorry by "app" i meant "web app". Anyway you can't share cookies between two different domains. If the apps are hosted in the same environment you might be able to get them to share sessions, but not sure with one being Core and one being an older version of ASP.NET. If you don't want to use a redirect with querystring maybe you could cause a postback via the browser instead. If you're using HTTPS then the data would be private